# specify beans to use when constructing a stub using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a web-service build using jax-ws deployed on tomcat 5.5.  In this web service, I have some methods that get and return java bean objects.  I created my stub using the wsimport tool given with java in the normal way: `wsimport address/service?wsdl`.

The wsimport tool creates all classes that allows me to access remote method and all the beans classes.

My problem is that I already have defined my beans in my code.  I do not want to change everywhere in my code which beans I use.  Indeed, I want to specify to the stub which beans
I want to use.

Moreover, the beans generated by wsimport are not exactly the sames; wsimport convert array into List.

Is there a way to specify to wsimport (or other stub constructor) which beans I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the way wsimport marshall and unmarshall the arrays.

About the customized classes please see [need to use custom classes instead of generated (by wsimport) in web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960267/need-to-use-custom-classes-instead-of-generated-by-wsimport-in-web-services)